# how change items in view of admin panel yii

Tags: yii, crud, cdetailview

I create admin panel in yii1  via CRUD. In list section display  news with status (1 and 2). But i need display "Publish" and "Archive" instead 1 and 2. I did this in view but this way wrong.How i can do it?

Comment: Take the time to show us your code at least, and someone might take the time to help you pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try change `zii.widgets.grid.CGridView` if you use it.
Something like this:

```
'columns'  => [
                    [
                        'type'  => 'html',
                        'name' => 'status',
                        'value' => '"<div class=helper>". (1 === $data->status) ? 'Archive' : 'Publish' ."</div>"',
                        'htmlOptions' => ['data-label' => 'Status']
                    ],
```